# $f(x) = 5 + 6x − 3x^2, \ x \in [−5, 3)$

Tags: polynomials

> $$f(x) = 5 + 6x − 3x^2,\ x \in [−5, 3)$$

Sketch the graph of each of the functions below and state the domain and the range of each function.

I found the $y$ intercept which is $5$. But the $x$ intercepts I can't seem to work out. Also how would I find the turning point, domain and range? Any advice/help/working out.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean when you say you found the $y$ intercept? Did you plug in $x=0$? Since $x\in[-5,3)$, that doesn't even make sense.

Comment: If x = 0 then y = 5

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)  x intercepts $$y=0$$ $$3x^2-6x-5=0$$ Can you find x?

2) $max f(x)$ in point $x_0=-b/2a=\frac{-6}{-6}=1,$  $y_0=5+6\cdot1-3 \cdot 1^2=8$

$f(-5)=-100 f(3)=-4$
therefore  range of the  function is $[-100,8]$ as $x \in [-5,3)$

Comment: Thank you so much I can't vote you up because of my reputation but thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

solve the equation $-3x^2+6x+5=0$ to find the x-intercept points.

calculate $x_0=-\frac{b}{2a}$ to find the x-coordinate of turning point.

Comment: I got 1. But I need two x intercepts.

Comment: @Orbit How do you know the function has two real zeroes (x-intercepts)? It's possible for a parabola to have one zero or none at all.

Answer (score 0):

The $y$ intercept of this function does not exist. This is because $f$ is defined only on the interval $[-5,3)$.

As for the $x$ intercept, think about what defines the $x$ intercept. The $y$ intercept is characterized by $x$ being $0$. What characterizes the $x$ intercept and how would you calculate it?